# In a new shell, move to directory of other current buffer being edited?

Tags: buffers, shell, directories

I am using emacs to edit Latex. My work flow is to open the latex file, open a new buffer in a separate window via `C-x 2`. Then moving the context into the new windowbuffer via `C-x o`, I type `M x shell` to open a terminal.

This is all fine but I then need to type in the changing of directories to get to the Latex file, and I do this frequently. So I would like to know if there is a quick way to open the shell in the current directory of the Latex file?

Comment: on my system it does just that (emacs 24.5.1).  Maybe check variable `default-directory`?

Comment: @JeanPierre, I am a bit of an amateur in Emacs, but how do I execute this `default-directory? I tried `M x default-directory' which did not work.

Comment: `default-directory` is a variable, so use `C-h v default-directory` to see the value of the default directory in the shell buffer that you opened up.

Comment: @Kevin,default-directory is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is "~/Documents/Latex/UCF/STA4102/2/"
Local in buffer 2.tex; global value is nil

  Automatically becomes permanently buffer-local when set.
  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate `stringp'.

Documentation:
Name of default directory of current buffer.  Should end with slash.
To interactively change the default directory, use command `cd'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do what you want is to open the shell in the window that displays the Latex file. That way, the shell opens up in the directory containing the Latex file. Then switch windows `C-x o` and switch buffers `C-x b` back to the Latex file. This is just a different ordering of the actions that you are currently taking.

Comment: Simple solution that works. Nice and clever :)